# Java and Python MergeSort

Tags: java, mergesort

I am new to Java and I have been trying to do MergeSort, in a similar way I did it in Python.
This is how I do it in Python:

```
def merge_sort(a):
    length = len(a)
    if length > 1:
        left = a[: len(a) // 2]
        right = a[len(a) // 2 :]

        merge_sort(left)
        merge_sort(right)

        merge(a, left, right)


def merge(a, left, right):
    length = len(a)
    left_half = len(left)
    right_half = len(right)
    i1, i2 = 0, 0
    for i in range(length):
        if i2 >= right_half or (i1 < left_half and left[i1] < right[i2]):
            a[i] = left[i1]
            i1 += 1
        else:
            a[i] = right[i2]
            i2 += 1
```

This is my Java code and it returns index error.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Merge_sort1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = {5, 3, 0, 1, 9, 6, 7, 4, 8, 2};
        System.out.println("Array before sorting");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

        mergeSort(a);

        System.out.println("Array after sorting");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }

    public static void mergeSort(int[] a) {
        if (a.length > 1) {
            int mid = a.length / 2;
            int[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, mid - 1);
            int[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, mid, a.length - 1);

            mergeSort(left);
            mergeSort(right);

            merge(a, left, right);
        }   
    }

    public static void merge(int[] a, int[] l, int[] r) {
        int i1 = 0;
        int i2 = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if(i2 >= r.length || (i1 < l.length && l[i1] < r[i2])) {
                a[i] = l[i1];
                i1++;
            a[i] = r[i2];
            i2++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I would really appreciate it if anyone can explain to me what I'm doing wrong and the best way to fix it.
Thank you

Comment: Note, the second argument of [copyOfRange](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-int:A-int-int-) is exclusive (not inclusive).

Comment: Also note, the *if* statement in *merge* should be an *if-else* one instead.

Comment: Also, what is the problem? Compiler error? Runtime exception? Unexpected behaviour? Please be concise and include error messages/stack traces and a [MVE] when applicable.

Answer (score 1):

The [copyOfRange](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-int:A-int-int-) call is erroneous; note that the second argument is exclusive rather than inclusive. Which means the second argument of the method **minus 1** is the last element to be copied. So when calling `copyOfRange(a, b, c)` for example, the array `a` is copied from index `b` to `c - 1`, not `c`.

Also, the *if* statement in `merge` should be an *if-else* one (you forgot the *else* part).

So here is the code fixed, with proper output:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        int[] a = {5, 3, 0, 1, 9, 6, 7, 4, 8, 2};
        System.out.println("Array before sorting");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

        mergeSort(a);

        System.out.println("Array after sorting");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }

    public static void mergeSort(int[] a) {
        if (a.length > 1) {
            int mid = a.length / 2;
            int[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, mid);
            int[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, mid, a.length);

            mergeSort(left);
            mergeSort(right);

            merge(a, left, right);
        }   
    }

    public static void merge(int[] a, int[] l, int[] r) {
        int i1 = 0;
        int i2 = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if(i2 >= r.length || (i1 < l.length && l[i1] < r[i2])) {
                a[i] = l[i1];
                i1++;
            }
            else {
                a[i] = r[i2];
                i2++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to explain what “exclusive” means in this context.